# Не сохраняется переменная javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование

Скачиваю методом get файл с сервера, и вывожу в console браузера. Всё выводится как надо, но если пытаюсь сохранить переменную и вывести её потом, выводится undefined. Помогите пожалуйста. Вот код:

```
var temp

$.get("http://192.168.1.108/photos/" + addresa[nowfile], function(data) {
  console.log(data); 
  temp = data
})

console.log(temp);
```

Comment: function(data) вызывается только когда данные появятся (через несколько секунд), а console.log(temp) срабатывает СРАЗУ без каких-либо задержек — до того, как данные успели загрузиться

Comment: Дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Comment: console.log(temp тоже находиться в функции

Comment: В том коде, который вы показали, оно находится не в функции.

Comment: $.get("http://192.168.1.108/photos/" + addresa[nowfile], function(data) {  console.log(data); temp = data})

Comment: Посмотрите внимательней

Comment: Это вы посмотрите внимательней. В месте `})` функция заканчивается, и console.log(temp) находится не в функции.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!